# Admob ad not show up when application id is the same in Google Play

Tags: android, admob

I uploaded an app to Google play yesterday, but Admob ad not showing up.
Detail explanation:
If I change the application id in `build.gradle` from 
applicationId `com.abcde.alphabetmatchinggame`
to a different name like
applicationId `com.abcde.alphabetmatching`,
then the ad will show up.

Since I have already published my app to Google play using package name (application id) `com.abcde.alphabetmatchinggame`, so I can not just rename the application id to something else as a work around.

To find out what's happening, I added the adListener and on the call back

```
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
```

The error is:

```
public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.
```

This doesn't make sense because changing to another application id that is different from the published one in Google play showing ads right away.

Then I create another ad unit and same thing no ad and same error code.

I am clueless now.  Should I just delete my published app and create a new release under different application id / package name?  But it's such a hassle to delete and wait for Google play to release.

Comment: have you just registered admob a/c?

Comment: yes, but it's showing ads if I change the application id to another one in build.gradle

Comment: I am facing this same problem, Did you find any solution?

Comment: same problem as well, please let me know if u have found a solution for this